# Need help to authenticate the user using Next-auth and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, next-auth, next.js13

I've created my back end DB using express and MongoDB as an separate server folder and the next app in another client folder.
This is my **app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js**

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export const authOptions = {
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        username: { label: "Username", type: "text", placeholder: "Username" },
        password: { label: "Password", type: "text", placeholder: "Password" },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        if (credentials.username == "admin" && credentials.password == "123")
          return { id: 1, name: "Santhosh", email: "santhosh@mail.com" };
        return null;
      },
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

it is working fine for now. But I need to authenticate the user cred here with the data in mongoose.
The mongoose document is created in the name of "Users" model.

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true }
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

export const User = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

How to approach it since the model is not created within the Next app outside instead ?